# 4 GB modules detect but fail in ThinkPad T510

Tags: memory, thinkpad

I have upgraded memory in at least 100 machines over the years, but I have never before seen this failure mode.

Laptop: Lenovo Thinkpad T510, Intel i5 M540 @ 2.53 GHz

These memory DIMMs work in memtest86+

```
2048 MB DDR3-1066 Hynix HMT325S6BFR8C-G7
2048 MB DDR3-1333 Hynix HMT325S6CFR8C-H9
```

During the run it writes:

```
RAM: 532 Mhz (DDR3-1064) - BCLK: 133
Timings: CAS 7-7-7-20 @ 64-bit Mode
```

I wanted to upgrade the 2x2GB to 2x4GB. I tried with one of these modules as the single DIMM in the machine:

```
4096 MB Hynix HMT451S6BFR8A-PB N0 AA (12800S - 11 13 B4)
4096 MB DDR3-1600 - Kingston HP16D3LS1KBG/4G
```

The system boots normally. Both are detected by memtest86+, but when the test starts the screeen turns to different colors after which the system reboots.

If I add a working 2 GB module, the testing stops progressing (the red + is blinking) shortly after the test starts, but the screen does not get different colors nor does it reboot.

During this run memtest86+ writes:

```
RAM: 532 Mhz (DDR3-1064) - BCLK: 133
Timings: CAS 7-7-7-20 @ 128-bit Mode
```

Booting GNU/Linux causes the system to crash shortly after boot (which is not that surprising given memtest86+'s behaviour).

The 4 GB modules have been used for 1 month in another system.

I suspected bad modules, and I had 7 more of the 4 GB Hynix module. All exhibit the same behaviour, which leads me to believe the modules are not bad, but somehow incompatible.

Looking at https://support.lenovo.com/dk/en/solutions/migr-75003 and https://support.lenovo.com/dk/en/solutions/migr-75377 it seems T510 should work fine with 4GB modules PC3-12800/DDR3-1600.

Looking at https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles/6muj31us.txt I can find no indication that 4 GB are unsupported in BIOS version 1.19 (which is installed). On the contrary there is evidence that > 4 GB is supported: version 1.24 mentions a bug, that causes memory to be *displayed* wrongly on 64-bit systems if > 4 GB is installed (i.e. version 1.24 clearly supports > 4 GB, and the only other released version after 1.19 is 1.20 which does not mention anything about memory either). The OS I installed was not 64-bit - thus should not be affected by the BIOS bug.

What is probable cause for the memory not working? Can I somehow verify that is correct? Can I configure the laptop to accept the 4 GB blocks?

Comment: The behavior indicates the device itself doesn't support 4 GB modules.  What makes you think it should?  Memory capability is something that can be addressed in a firmware update.  Have you tried upgrading to the current revision of the firmware designed to function on your device?  If you have documentation, indicating 4 GB modules should work, provide it within the body of your question.  Does the system boot with a single 4 GB module installed?  Update your question by editing it.

Comment: @Ramhound I looked on Crucial.  The Lenovo Thinkpad T510 does support 4GB RAM modules.

Comment: So have you updated the firmware?  Worst case is the memory still doesn’t work